# 503 error after app scales up a gear (jBoss - Openshift)

Tags: openshift

I'm running into some issues with my jBoss Openshift scalable app. It has been working fine for the longest time but today was the first time it tried to scale up by adding a gear. All the logs were clean except for haproxy.log.

I updated the haproxy config file as per this thread [Openshift Layer4 connection, App Won't Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299211/openshift-layer4-connection-app-wont-start). It seems to have fixed that issue but the problem still occurred.  This time, it was a timeout rather than a connection refused.

Below are the logs. Logs before 175/152729 represent the first 503 and those after represent the 503 after I updated the config file.

Any ideas?

```
[WARNING] 173/000937 (287321) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 173/000937 (287321) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 173/000937 (287321) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 173/000937 (287321) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 173/001157 (287321) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 23ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
[WARNING] 175/132222 (287321) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[ALERT] 175/132222 (287321) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/132534 (287321) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).
[WARNING] 175/133252 (287321) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10000ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 13 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/133252 (287321) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/133612 (287321) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/133636 (153678) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/133636 (153678) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/133646 (153678) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/133646 (153678) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/133652 (153678) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/133658 (153678) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/140641 (318379) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/140641 (318379) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/140643 (318379) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[ALERT] 175/140643 (318379) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/140646 (318379) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).
[WARNING] 175/140708 (318379) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/140708 (318379) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/141008 (318379) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/141011 (338788) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/141011 (338788) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/141011 (338788) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>404<3E>", check duration: 10ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/141011 (338788) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/141029 (338788) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/141032 (342087) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/141032 (342087) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/141032 (342087) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>404<3E>", check duration: 2ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/141032 (342087) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/141036 (342087) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/141201 (342087) : Server express/local-gear is UP (leaving maintenance).
[WARNING] 175/152729 (342087) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10003ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 2 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/152729 (342087) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/152922 (342087) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/152942 (252887) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/152942 (252887) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/152952 (252887) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10001ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/152952 (252887) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/153032 (252887) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/153053 (258844) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/153053 (258844) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/153103 (258844) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10006ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/153103 (258844) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/153110 (258844) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/153115 (258844) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN for maintenance.
[WARNING] 175/153600 (286688) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'stats' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/153600 (286688) : config : log format ignored for proxy 'express' since it has no log address.
[WARNING] 175/153610 (286688) : Server express/local-gear is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 10013ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
[ALERT] 175/153610 (286688) : proxy 'express' has no server available!
[WARNING] 175/153622 (286688) : Server express/local-gear is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "HTTP status check returned code <3C>200<3E>", check duration: 86ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
```

Comment: For scaling, have a read of https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-host-your-java-ee-application-with-auto-scaling/ and see if you have everything covered. One reason for problems is the application returning an error status for the URL that haproxy uses as a health status.

Comment: How did you deploy your application? Was it via git or via scp/sftp?